# Fastest way to multiply two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have two ranges in Excel of the same size, and I want to multiply them in another range using vba. For example:
Range 1: `Sheets("A").Range("A1:H200")`
Range 2: `Sheets("B").Range("A1:H200")`
Then I need:

```
Sheets("C").Range("A1:H200")= Range 1 * Range 2
```

That is, I need each cell of Sheet C to be the multiplication of the same cell in Sheets A and B.

Comment: `evaluate` is probably fastest but I don't know XD Array should be a close second?

Comment: Look into the R1C1 method of writing formulas - in short, R1C1 writes the formula *relative to the cell that its in*. This would allow you to select your range and enter the 'same' formula for all cells.

Comment: Your inputting 2 two dimensional table as a multiplication. This could be interpreted numerous ways. Are you talking about a matrix multiplication? Please elaborate on your expected results.

Comment: Yes, it would be a matrix multiplication, where the matrix are ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it nearly instantly:

```
Sheets("C").Range("A1:H200") = [INDEX(A!A1:H200*B!A1:H200,0)]
```

Comment: How do I use this piece of code if the range is defined by a vba variable?

Comment: I mean that the last row is defined by a vba variable (`Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`)

Comment: Sheets("C").Range("A1:H" & lastrow) = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(A!A1:H" & lastrow & "*B!A1:H" & lastrow & ",0)")`

Comment: And how can I add an `IFERROR`? I get some `#VALUE!`... I tried `Application.Evaluate("IFERROR(INDEX(A!A1:H" & lastrow & "*B!A1:H" & lastrow & ",0),"")")`, but it didn't work

Comment: `Sheets("C").Range("A1:H" & lastrow) = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(IFERROR(A!A1:H" & lastrow & "*B!A1:H" & lastrow & "),""),0)")`

Comment: I just realized that the previous formula was also not working :( `Sheets("C").Range("A1:H" & lastrow) = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(A!A1:H" & lastrow & "*B!A1:H" & lastrow & ",0)")`

Comment: I get only #VALUE! s

Comment: Usually when the paramter of an already answered question changes it should be a new post, but `Sheets("C").Range("A1:H" & lastrow) = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(IFERROR(A!A1:H" & lastrow & "*B!A1:H" & lastrow & ",""""),0)")` is tested and will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @N.Pavon The reason that you would want to ask it in a new question when changing the parameters, is we all have real jobs and the person who answered may not have the time to customize when new criteria are encountered.  I just happened to be on my break, but many times the quicker response will come from the community at a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the fastest is to use a Sub to manipulate the cell formula in `C`.

Try this, you get the idea...

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillFormula()
    Worksheets("C").Range("A1:H200").FormulaR1C1 = "=A!RC*B!RC"
End Sub
```